# .htaccess acting funky after moving site from Drupal to standalone

Tags: php, drupal, .htaccess

I recently tore down my full Drupal site and rebuilt the whole thing in my own framework from scratch.  The site is great.  But,  the problem is when you type a search in google for images.  When you click on an image for my site, instead of landing on the right page, it redirects to the home page.  Every URL is exactly the same / same content.  The only differece in the .htaccess is:

My site:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# GoDaddy Requires -MultiViews
Options -Multiviews
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Old Drupal Site:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's really frustrating.  Right now it's about 700 unique visitors a day and 500 of those land on the home page when about 80% percent of them were supposed to land on a different page from a google searched image.   Any ideas why this is happening?

-- I don't think the reason is because it was directing to /node/59(Nodes instead of specified paths).  I had clean urls enabled and it's redirecting to the home page for every searched image which is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess looks fine, I don't think that it has anything to do with it.

What you're looking for is some sort of script in that site that is checking for an "valid" referrer, or I'm suspecting that your loading some Javascript to to the following thing:

```
if (top.location != location) {
     top.location.href = document.location.href ;
}
```

Remove it. It's frame busting code, and has been an (awful) practice for many years in webdevelopment, but it doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You might try uncommenting and changing the following line in your sites/default/settings.php file.

```
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

This has solved problems that I've had when moving a site from my local development site to a remote production site.
Good Luck!